# Is --overrides an accepted option in drush 8.x?

Tags: 8, drush

I'm creating a build script and would like to include [the `--overrides` flag as describe in the documentation](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/#overrides). I'm using Drupal 8.0.0 and Drush 8.0.1 and I get the following:

> `drush make build.make.yml ~/Sites/built --prepare-install --overrides=dev.make --no-cache -y -vvv`
>
> Unknown option: --overrides.  See 'drush help make' for available options. To suppress this error, add the option --strict=0.

Am I missing something? Is this functionality not built yet?

Comment: Corrected an edit that removed tags from title. The tags are needed for the sentence to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be in the master branch, but not yet in 8.0.x.

Comment: The relevant commit: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/60ac0a23010a95cf684a3fee2c094557c0bd488b